# Error in npm install jdbc

Tags: node.js, jdbc, npm, mean-stack

I was facing certain several issues with some dependencies and some error which I can't figure out the exact reason for those errors.

Please, help me by providing required steps need to be performed.

Error seems to be looked like below:

```
C:\>npm install jdbc
> java@0.9.0 install C:\node_modules\java
> node-gyp rebuild
C:\node_modules\java>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
    [node-java] Error: not found: javac.exe
    gyp: Call to 'node findJavaHome.js' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp.
     while trying to load binding.gyp
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\node_modules\java
    gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\package.json'
    npm WARN !invalid#1 No description
    npm WARN !invalid#1 No repository field.
    npm WARN !invalid#1 No README data
    npm WARN !invalid#1 No license field.

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! java@0.9.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.9.0 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\DC250042\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-01T12_48_39_214Z-debug.log"
```

Comment: I'm not a regular node.js user, but the problem seems to be that you are calling `npm` from `C:\ `, you should call it from the folder containing your project instead.

Comment: It's complaining it can't find `javac.exe`. Have you installed the Java Development Kit (JDK) and not just the Java runtime (JRE)?

Comment: Yes I did installed jdk and set the environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same problem. Solved after get JDK (not JRE) and set JAVA_HOME to JDK home folder.

Build Fail:

```
   > java@0.9.1 install /tmp/app/node_modules/jdbc/node_modules/java
   > node-gyp rebuild       
   [node-java] Error: not found: javac
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp: Call to 'node findJavaHome.js' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
   gyp ERR! configure error
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/app/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
   gyp ERR! command "/tmp/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/app/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
   gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/app/node_modules/jdbc/node_modules/java
   gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
   gyp ERR! not ok
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! java@0.9.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.9.1 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /home/vcap/.npm/_logs/2019-02-03T06_06_30_610Z-debug.log
```

Build Succeed:

```
   > java@0.9.1 install /tmp/app/node_modules/jdbc/node_modules/java
   > node-gyp rebuild
   make: Entering directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/jdbc/node_modules/java/build'
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/javaObject.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/javaScope.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/methodCallBaton.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/nodeJavaBridge.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/utils.o
   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
   COPY Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
   make: Leaving directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/jdbc/node_modules/java/build'

   > java@0.11.0 install /tmp/app/node_modules/java
   > node-gyp rebuild

   make: Entering directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/java/build'
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/javaObject.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/javaScope.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/methodCallBaton.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/nodeJavaBridge.o
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/utils.o
   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
   COPY Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
   make: Leaving directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/java/build'

   > java@0.9.1 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/jdbc/node_modules/java
   > node postInstall.js


   > java@0.11.0 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/java
   > node postInstall.js

   added 14 packages from 16 contributors and audited 7320 packages in 57.174s
   found 7 vulnerabilities (1 low, 6 moderate)
   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```